# Upgrading Twig within Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony 2.3.1, which uses Twig 1.13.1

I want to use Twig 1.18.0. Is this possible?

I tried upgrading it to 1.18.0 via composer.phar, but this makes no odds within Symfony, which continues to use 1.13.1, which I suspect is part of the TwigBundle vendor.

The only version of Symfony which runs 1.18.0 is version 3, which I don't want to use at this point.

Comment: [Symfony 2.3.1 uses Twig `~1.11`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.3.1/composer.json). Are you sure you have your versions right? Why are you using the first release of 25 for Symfony 2.3? You're also incorrect in thinking that only Symfony 3.x runs Twig 1.18, as [the `composer.json` of Symfony 2.7 requires `~1.18`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/composer.json). You can also see that using [`~1.11` would load `1.18` anyways using the `~` operator](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions). Something's fishy.

Comment: If I look in Kernel.php, it has this: const VERSION         = '2.3.1'; and if I do version within Twig, it states 1.13.1 All I can tell you is what the software states it is.

Comment: Do a `composer update` on your project, and it will update to twig 1.18.

Comment: What version will that update Symfony to though? e.g. I did a composer update specifically on twig, but Symfony ignores that and just uses 1.13.1 since that is what TwigBridge bundle uses.